# Ms Access gives rubbish when updating a join column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Updating a column that is part of your selection criteria should be no problem I think/thought.
I still have a query that gives odd results:

```
update table1 as t1 
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.old_id
set t1.id = t2.id
```

I use table2 to map id to old_id.
table1.id and table2.id are both primary keys. table2.old_id is also unique.

It follows that table1.id will still be unique after this update.
**WRONG!** MS Access will make rumble of this, with some duplicate table.id values.

I think however this is the correct way of updating a column that is used in a join? How could we achieve the desired result in MS Access?

*Note: table2 is a mysql view accessed via ODBC.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> table1.id and table2.id are both
>   primary keys. table2.old_id is also
>   unique.
>
> It follows that table1.id will still
>   be unique after this update.

That ain't necessarily so.

It seems old_ID and (new) ID are of the same data type. A row in table1 that has no matching row in table2 based on the predicate (`table1.ID = table2.old_ID`) would not be updated. A different row could match a (new) ID value, hence get updated, with the same value as that row that didn't get updated.

Here's an example using Standard SQL (works in SQL Server 2008, not it Access/Jet) which I hope you can follow. Note I've re-written your `INNER JOIN` using an `EXISTS` construct to fit the logic of what I am trying to convey:

```
WITH Table1 (ID) AS
     (
      SELECT ID
        FROM (
              VALUES (1),
                     (2),
                     (3), 
                     (4)
             ) AS Table2 (ID)
     ), 
     Table2 (old_ID, ID) AS
     (
      SELECT old_ID, ID
        FROM (
              VALUES (1, 55),
                     (2, 99),
                     (3, 4)
             ) AS Table2 (old_ID, ID)
     )
-- ID of rows that will not be updated:
SELECT T1.ID
  FROM Table1 AS T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT * 
                     FROM Table2 AS T2
                    WHERE T1.ID = T2.old_ID
                  )
UNION ALL
-- updated IDs
SELECT T2.ID
  FROM Table2 AS T2
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM Table1 AS T1
                WHERE T1.ID = T2.old_ID
              );
```

The resultset:

```
ID
---
4   --<-- duplicate
55
99
4   --<-- duplicate
```

In other words, even though all the following are unique:

```
(table1.ID)
(table2.ID)
(table2.old_ID)
```

...the following may contain duplicates:

```
table1.ID
UNION ALL
table2.ID
```

Comment: I thought I've tested against this situation, but you are right this is what makes the join-update gives wrong results.
It is strange that the solution OMG Ponies describes is fundamentally refused by Access. It seems an update with a subselect doesn't work at all in Access. Documentation on Access is the poorest I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Using JOINs in UPDATE statements isn't consistently supported, which is why they aren't my habit to use.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 AS t1
   SET t1.id = (SELECT t2.id
                  FROM TABLE2 t2
                 WHERE t2.old_id = t1.id)
```

Comment: Thnx, but now I get the problem that the operation needs to be carried out on an updateable query. How do you handle in that situation?

Comment: The operation needs to be performed on a query that can be updated. The error message you would get in an english edition would be exactly this: "Operation must use an updatable query". It is MS-talk, I dont understand either.

Comment: I guess it might have to with the fact that table2 is an odbc view which access might fruitlessly want to lock.

Comment: @Exception e: The error relates to using an UPDATE statement - here's the [MS Knowledgebase article on resolving it](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168).

Comment: If I bypass the whole odbc by using local tables directly I get still the same errors. I've assigned as much permissions as possible, although IUSR_MACHINE is not explicily listed. Also note that with the innerjoin approach i updated the table without this error. This software is a f*ing piece of shit.

Comment: ACE/Jet SQL syntax doesn't support the Standard SQL scalar subquery syntax. It forces you use the proprietary JOINs  syntax (different to SQL Server's proprietary JOIN syntax) except when using aggregate set functions in which case you need to do it 'by hand'.

Comment: Have you tried a passthrough? That way you can use whatever SQL MySQL would use to do the job.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: The OP isn't updating the MySQL data, from what I understand.  Comment on the question for the OP to see your comment.